# looping median filter using python OpenCv

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, python

I want to run median blur for multiple images. I used this code to load the images

path = glob.glob("path_to_data/*.tif")

cv_img = []

for img in path:

```
n = cv2.imread(img, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
cv_img.append(n)
```

when I check the length of the input after loading into cv_img, I get the total number of images. But when I run the median blur with the code

for data in cv_img:

```
cv2.medianBlur(image, 3)
```

I expect to get the same length as the input but I don’t.

I need help so I can run the median filter for all the images and write out the result for each input file.

Any assistance?

Comment: Please provide example code of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a list of images: (`image_list`)

```
for image in image_list:
   cv2.medianBlur(image,3)
```